# Trying to read the active window title when it changes in Console Application

Tags: c#, delegates, console-application

I am trying to make a program that writes the active window title, whenever it changes to the console window.

Here's my code, It does work in a winform application but not in a console application, I couldn't figure out what's wrong.
 Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
    private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
    private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetActiveWindowTitle() + "\r\n");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WinEventDelegate dele = null;

        Program a = new Program();
        dele = new WinEventDelegate(a.WinEventProc);
        IntPtr m_hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["The client thread that calls `SetWinEventHook` must have a message loop in order to receive events."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd373640) Threads in a console application don't have message loops. Unless you build one:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetMessage(out Message lpMsg, IntPtr hwnd, int wMsgFilterMin, int wMsgFilterMax);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int TranslateMessage(Message lpMsg);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int DispatchMessage(Message lpMsg);
```

Then replace `Console.ReadKey()` with

```
Message msg;
while (true) { 
    int result = GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
    if (result == 0) break;
    if (result == -1) throw new Win32Exception();
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);
}
```

I'm being lazy and taking the `Message` structure from `System.Windows.Forms`. You could add the definition of that separately if you don't want to take the dependency.

Since this thread is now occupied with processing messages, you probably want to do this on a separate dedicated thread if you want to do other processing.